# How to update all WebView tabs when a login is detected?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

It seems I am not finding the right term for searching my problem. I have an app now that is almost complete with one problem. First I would like to explain the app first. The app is a webview app with 5 tabs on the bottom navigation bar. I am using the official Flutter dev team [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

**I have 2 problems btw, they are in a blockquote**

Now the remaining problems is that when i logged in to the url that I've set in the one of the tabs where I used webview, it produces

> **(1)** an error (image below, for some reason the error wont appear again on my emulator (it happened on the first time) BUT on my phone
>   it appears)  in the tab I used to login and not redirects
>   automatically to the URL ive set

[image: Error produced]

> **(2)** and not all tabs refreshes automatically to detect the login event (I need to navigate in the url of the website and go back to
>   detect the login event (which is what I dont want to happen)

below are my codes:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:syncshop_webview/widgets/cart_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop_webview/widgets/categories_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop_webview/widgets/home_page.dart';
import 'package:syncshop_webview/widgets/profile_account.dart';
import 'package:syncshop_webview/widgets/search_page.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
int _selectedPage = 2;
final _pageOptions = [
  CategoriesPage(),
  SearchPage(),
  HomePage(),
  CartPage(),
  ProfileAccount(),
];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Sync Shop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedPage,
        children: _pageOptions,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: _selectedPage,
          onTap: (int index) {
            setState((){
      _selectedPage = index;
            });
          },
          items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.category), title: Text("Categories"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), title: Text("Search"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("Home"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_cart), title: Text("Cart"),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), title: Text("Profile"),
          ),
          ],
          ),
      ),
      );
  }
}
```

**one of my tabs, specifically where the user should login**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class ProfileAccount extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _ProfileAccountState createState() => _ProfileAccountState();
}

class _ProfileAccountState extends State<ProfileAccount> with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ProfileAccount>{

WebViewController _myController;
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(
            body: WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://syncshop.online/en/login',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
              _myController = controller;
            },
          onPageFinished: (initialUrl) {
              _myController.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].style.display='none';");
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is an issue in API level 28 or higher. They disabled `android:usesCleartextTraffic` for security purposes. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834600/11833795) you can find the solutions.

Comment: got it thanks. But do you have any idea how to fix my (2) problem ? Ive been searching for hours now and i cant seem to find the exact solution

Comment: I haven't used flutter much, but if you need help in the logical part(i.e. to handle flow), I can guide you. For that, I need detailed information about what exactly you want to do(code not needed).

Comment: I fixed it :) my problerm right now is different can I pm you ?

Comment: you can ask here, it'll help someone else.

Answer (score 1):

make sure to use `https` instead of `http` or you can opt out your app to allow http traffic.

Comment: im using ```https``` for all the links